# Collision Responses with many different types

Tags: collision-detection

I'd like to write an efficient Collision Response code, that does not use instanceof/type checks that often (if  possible)

my current implementation is something like this:

```
GameObject.collidesWith(GameObject other)
{
    if(other instanceof ConcreteType1)
    {
        //do response with Concrete Type 1
    }else if (other instanceof ConcreteType2)
        // do response with Concrete Type 2
    }
}
```

`GameObject` is the base class of everything. 
Is there a possibility to avoid instanceof and type checks?

Comment: Make base classes like, BasicConcrete, then all new Concrete must extend this class, unless if you want different behavior for each concrete type

Comment: What is your requirement about this? Why don't you want to use `instanceof`? What language are you using?

Comment: Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch , maybe you can use this idiom in your programming language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the part I currently need to work on for my own game..

What I've reasoned out so far is that I can have a `CollisionBox` on the `GameObject` which contains all the collision boundary information. Collisions are checked by `GameObject.isColliding(other)` - where the two `CollisionBoxes` compare whether they intersect.

```
if (gameObject.isColliding(other))
{
    gameObject.doCollision(other);
}
```

then the `GameObject` has a `doCollision` method which is overridden for various `GameObjects`

```
public GameObject
{
    CollisionBox collisionBox;
    CollisionType collisionType;

    public void doCollision(GameObject other)
    {
        switch(other.CollisionType)
        {
            case Inelastic: //etc
            case Elastic: //etc
            case Consumable: //(this one is for bullets, upgrades, pickups - 
                // things you collide with but the collision doesn't affect motion)
        }
    }
}
```

As you can maybe guess, `CollisionType` is an enum which is assigned to `GameObject`.

---

That was my initial plan anyway. Now I hope to take some inspiration from [Collision detection and response in an Entity System](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/33731/52682) - though I'll still probably end up with some type of "collisionType enum" to broadly group a type of collision.